# Find website reviews not on website?

Tags: google-search

Basically I want to see the reviews a website has but I don't want to look at the reviews they put on their own website.

I Googled "Websitename review -Site:example.com"

However I was still seeing results for `example.com/example`.

How can I remove all pages from the website from my Google search?

Comment: Just to clarify, where exactly did you put the quotation marks, if you used quotation marks at all? Quoting the entire phrase won't work. Also, are you willing to share the actual website name or an example of another website that also does this?

Comment: This question would be more suitable for our sister site: [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @barrycarter There were no quotation marks. The marks were to show exactly what went into the search query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I Googled "Websitename review -**Site**:example.com"

The `site:` operator should be all lowercase.

Comment: Thank you! When I was looking up how to do Google searches with search parameters I didn't see anything that told me "Site must be lowercase". Stupid mistake by me for assuming.